# Bootstrap gird row same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked a number of times but for my problem the proposed solutions are not working.

I am presenting a PDF to a user in a modal along side a form. Image below.

[image]

The problem I am having is that the iframe is set at 100% for the maximum size it will go to at 100% is as per the image.

If I give is a fixed size of 435px; it sizes to the right aspect for my screen. As I need this to be screen agnostic I want it to size its self according to the modal that it appears in.

I have tried using the working example from here http://www.bootply.com/92230 and this example is the same as I have seen all over the web this morning.

The HTML for this is

```
<div class="row">
     <div id="equalheight">
          <div id="loa" class="col-md-6 demo NotShown">
               <iframe src="\\sqlmuldvwsk06.ukskpre.santanderuk.pre.corp\Public\CMCFileUpload\LOAFiles\SRA557034_321043.004.pdf" class="mh100Percent mw100" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
                                        <p>It appears your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
               </iframe>
           </div>
           <div id="custDetails" class="col-md-12 demo">
           ...
           </div>

      </div>
 </div>
```

The reason I am having to use an iFrame is because I am working on an application that is for internal use on a corporate LAN and when I try and embed the pdf as an object I get an Access Denied error.

Also, when an event if fired, the div custDetails is resized to a `col-md-6` and when the modal is finished with the divs are resized \ reclassed.

Any and all help on how to show the iFrame the same size as the form next to it would be great.

thanks

Simon

Comment: What code you have used to achieve equal height ?

Comment: When I need to have things aligned the way you need (at least, this is my understanding), I always tend to use **tables** in your case, I would use a table whose width is set to 100% with one single row and two cells, each cell assigned a width of 50% and the contents within each cell (like your PDF) the width of 100%.

Comment: I had the same issue for several brother´s div. My solution was use the next properties...     display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; align-items: stretch;

Comment: @AmanRawat the css as per this link http://www.bootply.com/92230.  I have tried the code without the pdf and just standard div's and this works fine so the issue is with the iframe I belive.

Comment: @EliasMP can you show me a fuller example in an answer please.

Comment: @FDavidov I fear this might be the only way I achieve this

Comment: Why "fear"? It is done all over the Web! Just check for instance Facebook's login, Username and Password are arranged in a table to get the desired alignment.

Comment: fear may be too strong a word, but just because its done everywhere (and works) doesn't mean its best practice.

Comment: @FDavidov tried it with the table, and it just brought the iframe down to the centre of the cell. putting a height of 100% on the iframe element and taking it out of its div did nothing for the size

Comment: Did you check margins, vertical and horizontal alignments, etc.?

Comment: @SimonPrice the code you are using is not doing what you want its adding padding to the bottom so that it can give same color. So it appears like they are of same height. `http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/`

Comment: By the way, in your code you are using `col-md-12` or the like classes which have some built-in formats. I would check removing those classes.

Comment: @AmanRawat tried that first... didn't work with the iframe.

Comment: @FDavidov, yes have removed the col-md classes and still the same. was also one of my early checks. and yes, I have checked margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
    .row-eq-height {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }

    iframe {
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>

<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div id="loa" class="col-md-6 demo NotShown">
        <iframe
            src="\\sqlmuldvwsk06.ukskpre.santanderuk.pre.corp\Public\CMCFileUpload\LOAFiles\SRA557034_321043.004.pdf"
            class="mh100Percent mw100" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
            <p>It appears your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="custDetails" class="col-md-6 demo">
        ...
    </div>

</div>
```

Hope this will work

Comment: ok, so that has worked and put it to the right size, but now I can no longer scroll on the PDF file.   Changing scrolling to yes, and removing it completely doesn't help.

Comment: Update the new code changes you have done and where the problem is coming now

Comment: the problem that I ham having is with the overflow, its over flowing the everything rather than just the iframe.

Comment: sorted! just put a specific overflow on that containing div.  thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here we go...

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; align-items: stretch;">
    <div style="background-color:red; border: 2px solid black;">DIV 1<br/>DIV 1<br/>DIV 1<br/>DIV 1<br/></div>
    <div style="background-color:green; border: 2px solid black;">DIV 2DIV 1<br/>DIV 2<br/>DIV 2<br/>DIV 2<br/>DIV 2<br/>DIV 2<br/>DIV 2<br/></div>
    <div style="background-color:blue; border: 2px solid black;">DIV 3</div>
    <div style="background-color:gray; border: 2px solid black;">DIV 4</div>
    <div style="background-color:yellow; border: 2px solid black;;">DIV 5</div>
</div>
```

Hoping it helps...